# Mongoose ODM saves wrong model name in MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, odm

Hello Stackoverflowers!

I got a strange issue with Mongoose creating a collection named "Safes".

here is my example code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodb:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true })

const Safe = mongoose.model('Safe', { name: String })

const safe = new Safe({ name: 'foobar' })
safe.save().then(() => console.log('done'))
```

when I open the database shell and issue this command:

```
mongo test --eval "db.getCollectionNames()"
```

its responds with:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("f9cfa8b9-58e2-40b8-9907-ecd18039935a") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.6
[ "saves" ]
```

Now, I tried to create a model with a collection names "Safes" and mongoose seems to change it from safes > saves ...

Has mongoose some kind of protected models that cannot be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like they set a rule on words ending with "fe" because they normally convert to plural as "ves" (knife -> knives).

You can set your own collection name by adding another argument to Schema:

```
const safeSchema = new Schema({ name: String }, { collection: 'safes' })
```

Comment: This is the solution... Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

Mongooses `util.toCollectionName` generates a name of the collection based on the Schema name. It does use some regexes, one of them being:

```
  [/(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$/gi, '$1$2ves'],
```

Which maches sa*fe* and replaces it with sa*ves*.

[source](https://github.com/vkarpov15/mongoose-legacy-pluralize/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Thank you too, now I know that the regex can fail for some words! ;D